# Angular.js Controller is Loading after the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Here I'm trying to return the url of each id I receive, but the url is generated asynchronously, as a result its taking time to get generated and I'm unable to put it into the view. How can I make it wait till the data is fetced from PouchDB and Url is generated

> controller

```
    $scope.getColour = function(id) {
        var texture_array = [];
        texture_array = photoList.data.economy.concat(photoList.data.luxury, photoList.data.premium);
        var db = PouchDB('new_test4');
        var obj = {};
        var array = [];
        var i;
        // console.log(texture_array.length)
        for (i = 0; i < texture_array.length; i++) {
            //var id = texture_array[i].image_url;
            if (texture_array[i].image_url == id) {
                db.getAttachment(id, id, function(err, blob_buffer) {
                    if (err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    } else {
                        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob_buffer);
                        console.log(url);
                        return url;
                    }
                });
            }

        }

    };
```

> html

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="photoOuterObj in remainingEconomyColour " ng-class=" $index? '' : 'active'">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="photoInnerObj in photoOuterObj">
        <div class="premium-carousel-image">
            <a class="color-image"> <img src="{{getColour(photoInnerObj.image_url)}}" alt="Image" /></a>
            <div class="ambience-button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is **remainingEconomyColour**  list in controller?

Comment: its nothing but what inside `photoList.data.economy` array

Comment: Can you make a fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the `getColor` function to return a promise:

```
$scope.getColourPromise = function(id) {
    var texture_array = [];
    texture_array = photoList.data.economy.concat(photoList.data.luxury, photoList.data.premium);
    var db = PouchDB('new_test4');
    var obj = {};
    var array = [];
    var i;
     //Create deferred object
    var defer = $q.defer();
    // console.log(texture_array.length)
    for (i = 0; i < texture_array.length; i++) {
        //var id = texture_array[i].image_url;
        if (texture_array[i].image_url == id) {
            db.getAttachment(id, id, function handler(err, blob_buffer) {
                if (err) {
                    //return console.log(err);
                    //reject on error
                    defer.reject("db ERROR "+err);
                } else {
                    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob_buffer);
                    console.log(url);
                    //resolve with url;
                    defer.resolve(url);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    //return promise
    return defer.promise;
};
```

Because the `getAttachment` method executes the `getHandler` function asynchronously **after** the `getColour` function completes, it can't return a value, but it can resolve a defer object.

Use `ng-init` to fetch the url and attach it the `ng-repeat` iterator object:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="innerObj in photoOuterObj">
    <!-- use ng-init to do the fetch -->
    <div ng-init="innerObj.urlObj = fetchURL(innerObj)">
        <a class="color-image"> <img ng-src="{{innerObj.urlObj.url}}" alt="Image" /></a>
        <div class="ambience-button">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The fetch function:

```
$scope.fetchURL = function(itemObj) {
    var urlObj = {};
    urlObj.url = "default.jpg";
    var promise = $scope.getColourPromise(itemObj.image_url);
    promise.then(function (url) {
        urlObj.url = url;
    });
    return urlObj;
});
```

The fetch initially returns an object with the `url` property set to a default value. When the promise resolves, it will be set to the fetched value. The watcher created the double curly bracket `{{ }}` expression will update the DOM.

Avoid using asynchronous functions in an interpolation `{{ }}` because they get called multiple times every digest cycle.

Comment: georgeawg I'm getting getColourPromise as undefined